# Composition API global state is not updating the DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

To have a Global state using Composition API.

but changes in the state of the composable are not reflected to the DOM of the component.

**useProducts.js**

```
import { reactive, toRefs} from "vue";

export default function useProducts() {
  // STATE
  const state = reactive({
    title: "old title"
  });
  // METHODS
  const changeTitle = function (title) {
    state.title = title;
    console.log(state.title, "the state changed here");
  }

  return {
    ...toRefs(state),
    changeTitle,
  };
}
```

**catalog.vue** I have hooked at the product title, it's showing the initial state

```
<template>
  <q-page class="full-height full-width">
    <h4>Products {{ title }}</h4>  <!-- old title -->
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
  ...
  setup() {
    const { title } = useProducts();
    return {
      title,
    };
  },
 ...
</script>
```

**app.vue** lets change the title after 3 sec from "old title" to "New Title"

```
  setup() {
    const { changeTitle } = useProducts();
    onMounted(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        changeTitle("New title");
      }, 3000); // we want to change the title for the entire App
    });
  },
```

when the app initialize the **catalog.vue** is showing the correct *title* of the product state. but after *Three seconds* the title did not change.

the title in the **catalog.vue** remains "old title" even after a call for changeTitle() in **app.vue**

Comment: This is local state. You can debug and make sure that useProducts is called for each component instance. Wrapping `reactive` call with another function won't and can't change anything, it's absolutely the same as calling it inside setup.

Comment: I see, so the state needs to be outside the useProducts. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, the reactive state is to be declared outside **useProducts()**

```
import { reactive, toRefs} from "vue";
// STATE
const state = reactive({
  title: "old title"
});
export default function useProducts() {
  // METHODS
  const changeTitle =  (title) =>{
    state.title = title;
    console.log(state.title, "the state changed here");
  }
  return {
    ...toRefs(state),
    changeTitle,
  };
}
```